# Changing Img Src through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery

Hi I am trying to change the images in my gallery when the page loads. I am trying to do it the way that has been most posted about on here

```
function changeImg(){
            var img1 =  document.getElementById("wows1_0");                
            img1.src = "WOWSlider/data1/images/ContactSupport.jpg";
        }
```

then on calling it here

```
<body onload="changeImg()">
```

and here is the code of my gallery

```
<div id="wowslider-container1" class="grid_7 alignGallery">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
        <li><img src="WOWSlider/data1/images/BookARoom.jpg" alt="full screen slider" title="full screen slider" id="wows1_0"/></li>
        <li><img src="WOWSlider/data1/images/ContactSupport.jpg" alt="ContactSupport" title="ContactSupport" id="wows1_1"/></li>
    </ul></div>
<div class="ws_thumbs">
    <div>
        <a href="#wows1_0" title="full screen slider"><img src="WOWSlider/data1/tooltips/bookaroom.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#wows1_1" title="ContactSupport"><img src="WOWSlider/data1/tooltips/contactsupport.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>               
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
```

But every time I call the function The images are never changed.

I would be very grateful if anyone could provide any guidance or assistance.

Comment: I don't see any element with id **wows1_0**, and you are setting the image once at page loading. Do you see any error in the javascript console?

Comment: The element with the id `wows1_0` is in line 3 of the last snippet, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, I am creating this page in real time depending on what option is clicked. So i want to change the img sources depending on what is clicked, But first i needed to find out if i could change the img src but so far these answers haven't solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to preload images first:

```
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image()
            images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
    }
}
preload(
    "WOWSlider/data1/images/ContactSupport.jpg",
    "WOWSlider/data1/images/OtherImage.jpg"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the body onLoad.
Second, this should be your html script:

```
<body>
<div id="wowslider-container1" class="grid_7 alignGallery">
    <div class="ws_images">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="WOWSlider/data1/images/BookARoom.jpg" alt="full screen slider" title="full screen slider" id="wows1_0"/></li>
            <li><img src="WOWSlider/data1/images/ContactSupport.jpg" alt="ContactSupport" title="ContactSupport" id="wows1_1"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        changeImg();
    </script>
    <div class="ws_thumbs">
        <div>
            <a href="#wows1_0" title="full screen slider"><img src="WOWSlider/data1/tooltips/bookaroom.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#wows1_1" title="ContactSupport"><img src="WOWSlider/data1/tooltips/contactsupport.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>               
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</body>
```

and this should be your javascript:

```
function changeImg(){
    var img1 =  document.getElementById("wows1_0");            
    img1.src = "WOWSlider/data1/images/ContactSupport.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the onload event with a javascript right before the closing `body` tag.
Are you looking for something like this?

```
var $img = document.getElementById('yourImg');
var path = 'http://your-new-path-to-image.com';
$img.src = path;
// or
// $img.setAttribute('src', path);
```

http://codepen.io/codelabr/pen/RNZobB

Best regards